# AngularJS Routes User Back to Default When Coming From External Source

Tags: angularjs, adal

I'm using AngularJS with ADAL for authentication.

When I close a support ticket in my web app I send the client who submitted the ticket an email containing a link that he or she can click to reopen the issue.  The link is formatted as http://www.ourwebsite.com/#/support/XXXX where XXXX is a GUID created by WebAPI and stored in our database.

In the routing tables in the app.js file I have it set up so that app/support/:id is supposed to load reopenTicket.html using the reopenTicketController controller.  The controller is then supposed to grab the GUID using $routeParams.

However, the way it's working right now is when I click the link in the email to test it, it redirects me to http://www.ourwebsite.com/#/support as expected but after a few seconds I'm redirected to the login screen (which is what we've set up as the

```
.otherwise({redirect:'/login'});
```

I do not have requireADLogin on the

```
.when('/support')
```

so I know it's not because I'm not authenticated.  Is this an issue with AngularJS not being loaded because I didn't hit the root first?  Or is this an issue with ADAL?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect using routeprovider like these:

```
$routeProvider.when('/support/:id');
```

And then get the value using:

```
var ticketID = $routeParams.id;
```